# Dajaxice only registers one function

Tags: javascript, django

I am using a Django Ajax framework called Dajaxice. Here is a link: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

This is the JS Console error: `TypeError: Dajaxice.content.rm_fav is not a function`

This is `ajax.py`:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from content import models
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def rm_fav(request, pk):
    dajax = Dajax()
    id = '#' + str(pk)
    dajax.assign(id, 'value', 'Favorite')
    return dajax.json()

@dajaxice_register
def fav(request, pk):
    dajax = Dajax()
    id = '#' + str(pk)
    dajax.assign(id, 'value', 'Success!')
    return dajax.json()
```

Simple code, it just assigns or unassigns the "success!" after the user clicks "Favorite".

This is the JS function that is called:

```
function checkFav(object) {
    if (object.value == 'Favorite') {
        Dajaxice.content.fav(Dajax.process, {'pk': object.id}); 
    }
    else {
        Dajaxice.content.rm_fav(Dajax.process, {'pk': object.id}); 
    }
}
```

The `fav()` function works without a hiccup. But `rm_fav()` is not even recognized!

Comment: Hi, I hope you did find the solution. I'm getting same error and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `pythonX.Y manage.py collectstatic`.